# Kezboard tzping strange characters (Ubuntu)

Tags: keyboard, wine

Mz kez board is printing strange characters even though kezboard lazout in settings shows no problem

Following are numbers one to yero +ěščřžýáíé

This happened after I installed a few games using wine.

Tried this didn§t work

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

[image]

Anz help is appreciated

Please pardon the spell errors it is due to the issue with kezboard.

Comment: Figured to use Virtual kezboard now , since mz password has special characters now unavailabe on the kezboard

Comment: Looks like your 'y' and 'z' are swapped, so maybe your keyboard locale is set to a non-native language.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine I can§t tzpe numbers and szmbols and some szmbols like @ are completelz missing. Using a virtual kezboard to even tzpe mz password.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine It is the [Czech keyboard layout](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Windows_Czech_keyboard_layout.svg), I am pretty familiar with it. :-)

Comment: @Melebius Oh looks awesome. Those characters must be some kind of like umlauts or phonetics. I was not able to find `@`  symbol yesterday and so was not able to input my password. I see the @ symbol now. And then figured out Virtual keyboard from settings to just input my password :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this going in recovery mode and selecting dpkg repair broken packages.

```
1234567890 !@#$%^&*()
```

All keys seem to work correctly.

Also had to redo some brightness settings inorder to fix a less brightness issue arised after this.

Editing this file
`emacs -nw /etc/default/grub`

adding `acpi_backlight=video` after quiet splash

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=video"
```

And running `grub update`
and reboot
bringing back the brightness to normal